# Structure node pointers assignment

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, linked-list, structure

i have a homework that contains structure nodes, and in one of the functions, is written current->next->Firstname, and my question is:
what is the datatype of current->next->Firstname? 
thanks
.
the relevant parts of the code is the following:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char Lastname[50];
    char Firstname[50];
    char Initials[50];
    char Mobile[50];
    char Class[50];
    char InitialSort[50];
    char RandomSort[50];

    struct node *next;
} node;

node *HEAD=NULL;

// more code here.

void sortedInsert(node** head_ref,node* new_node)
{
    node* current;
    // Special case for the head end
    if (*head_ref == NULL || (*head_ref)->Firstname >= new_node->Firstname)
    {
        new_node->next = *head_ref;
        *head_ref = new_node;
    }

    else
    {
        // Locate the node before the point of insertion
        current = *head_ref;
        while (current->next!=NULL && strcmp(current->next->Firstname, new_node->Firstname)<0 )
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        new_node->next = current->next;
        current->next = new_node;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. "with a datatype like say option". What is "option"? It is not shown in your code and is not a native data type.

Comment: @Jeroen Van de Kaai As for me then I have not understood the question.

Comment: if option = current->next->Firstname, how should i delcare option? int, char char* , node* etc

Comment: you guys, i only have 7 reputation points and you shot me down.. i was trying to make my question as clear as i could..give new people a chance...

Comment: `char *option = current->next->Firstname`. But note that `option` will then be a pointer to the original data. It is not a copy.

Comment: We didn't shoot you down. Just asking for clarification so that we can help you with the correct answer. Don't worry about the rep. Just concentrate on learning and getting your work done.

Answer (score 0):

Any array is implicitly a pointer to the first element. So char Firstname[50] is just char* Firstname with 50 bytes allocated. Your type would then be a char*.

To follow the pointers understand that the struct is just a large set of allocated data. So current->next is just reading the address of the next node in the list. From there it asks to find the Firstname variable. This will jump to the address of the first element of Firstname for the 'next' node.